# Confused with If then else complex condition

Tags: php, arrays

I' am creating a menu using array. I' am currently stuck at the point where am confused how to show all children of the menu. Below is the code:

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php
$get_admin_menu = get_admin_menu(); 
$get_admin_submenu = get_admin_submenu(); 
foreach( $get_admin_menu as $menu ){
    $mi = 1;
    $menu_title = $menu["title"];
    $menu_slug = $menu["slug"];
    $menu_url = $menu["url"];

    echo "<li class=\"dropdown\">";
    echo "<a href=\"$menu_url\">";
    echo $menu_title;
    echo "</a>";

    $si = 0;
    $total = count($get_admin_submenu);
    foreach( $get_admin_submenu as $menu ){
        $mi++;
        $submenu_title = $menu["title"];
        $submenu_slug = $menu["slug"];
        $submenu_parent = $menu["parent"];
        if( $menu_url == $submenu_parent ){
            $si++;
            if( $si == 1 ){ echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">"; }
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"$submenu_parent?page=$submenu_slug\">";
            echo $submenu_title;
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
        if( $si == 1 ){ echo "</ul>"; break; }
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
        </ul>
```

**The above code renders **
[image]

**The outcome of this code should be**
[image]

**This is the code, how the menu and submenu are catered into the array**

```
    /* Add Administrator Menu */
$add_admin_menu = array();
function add_admin_menu( $args ) {
    global $add_admin_menu;
    return $add_admin_menu[] = $args;
}

/* Get Administrator Menu */
function get_admin_menu(){
    global $add_admin_menu;
    return $add_admin_menu;
}

/* Add Administrator Submenu */
$add_admin_submenu = array();
function add_admin_submenu( $args ) {
    global $add_admin_submenu;
    return $add_admin_submenu[] = $args;
}

/* Get Administrator Submenu */
function get_admin_submenu(){
    global $add_admin_submenu;
    return $add_admin_submenu;
}

function recursive_array_search($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
            $current_key = $key;
            if($needle === $value or (is_array($value) and recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
                    echo $current_key;
            }
    }
}

function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
         if ($val[$key] == $value) {
                 return $k;
         }
   }
   return false;
    }

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Dashboard",
        "slug" => "dashboard",
        "url" => "dashboard.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Media",
        "slug" => "media",
        "url" => "media.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Manage Pages",
        "slug" => "pages",
        "url" => "pages.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Plugin",
        "slug" => "plugin",
        "url" => "plugin.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Users",
        "slug" => "users",
        "url" => "users.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Tools",
        "slug" => "tools",
        "url" => "tools.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Settings",
        "slug" => "settings",
        "url" => "settings.php"
    );
    add_admin_menu($args);


    /* Media */
    $args = array(
        "title" => "Media Manager",
        "slug" => "media-manager",
        "parent" => "media.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Media Settings",
        "slug" => "media-settings",
        "parent" => "media.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    /* Pages */
    $args = array(
        "title" => "View All",
        "slug" => "view-all",
        "parent" => "pages.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Add New",
        "slug" => "add-new",
        "parent" => "pages.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Template Manager",
        "slug" => "template",
        "parent" => "pages.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    /* Settings */
    $args = array(
        "title" => "General",
        "slug" => "general",
        "parent" => "settings.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Mail Server",
        "slug" => "mail-server",
        "parent" => "settings.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);

    $args = array(
        "title" => "Security",
        "slug" => "security",
        "parent" => "settings.php"
    );
    add_admin_submenu($args);
```

Comment: Read it fast but maybe the problem occured here: `if( $si == 1 ){ echo "</ul>"; break; }` You break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You break the loop after first menu sub-element. At the end of the loop you have:

```
if( $si == 1 ) { echo "</ul>"; break; }
```

Try this one here:

```
if( $si >= ($total - 1) ) { echo "</ul>"; break; }
```

Comment: if `$menu_url` != `$submenu_parent` this condition with never match. It's easier to put `if ($si > 0) ...` after the foreach loop. Isn't it ?